# Force windows laptop to always use my dedicated GPU on power and integrated GPU on battery

Tags: windows, laptop, graphics-card, windows-11, gpu

I have an Intel OMEN laptop. It has horrible battery life (about 2h45m) because it's a high-performance "gaming" laptop.

I have two different uses for my laptop that are a bit opposing. For school, I need the laptop to last through as many classes as possible on battery, only doing basic things like Google Docs in Chrome. For personal use, it stays plugged in and I want as much performance as possible. My laptop has an integrated Intel GPU and a GTX 1650.

When my laptop is on battery, I want it to use the integrated GPU to save power. When it's plugged in, I want it to use the dedicated GPU for maximum performance.

I've tried messing with settings in the NVIDIA control panel, but it doesn't seem to work. I've also tried messing with my power plan but that didn't seem to affect it either. Windows GPU settings don't appear to have an option to do what I want. It seems to mostly prefer my integrated GPU but it does seem to use the dedicated GPU for a couple games.

Comment: I think, overall, your question is on-topic here, but software recommendation requests are off-topic here.  To prevent your good question from being closed, you may want to edit the last sentence.  As a moderator of the Software Recommendations SE, I'm fine if you post a similar question on Software Recommendations SE (https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/), as long as you edit the question on that SE to specifically ask for software recommendations.

Comment: Also, you may want to search for duplicates here, as I know I've read some similar questions in the past (although they may not be duplicates).

Comment: When the GTX 1650 is used, how do you know?  Do the fans suddenly spin up?

Comment: Does this answer help you? https://superuser.com/a/1186518/380110

Comment: And I'd assume at least on battery it's already doing what you want. Of course, the default on demand mode is software triggered so as long as you don't use graphically demanding software (you say you don't) it should work with the iGPU Intel always.

Comment: @EndAnti-SemiticHate Task manager separately shows me the usage for my integrated graphics and the dedicated GPU under the performance setting.

Comment: Thanks. Which Windows version?  Curious... do the fans spin up each time too?

Comment: Edition Windows 11 Home Insider Preview
Version 23H2
Installed on ‎2023-‎10-‎26
OS build 25982.1000
Experience Windows Feature Experience Pack 1000.25982.1000.0
TL;DR Windows 11 Canary Dev Beta
Honestly I haven't paid much attention to the fans

Comment: @EndAnti-SemiticHate On the answer you linked, it's already set to auto-select.

Comment: @ChanganAuto On power, I've used some websites that literally max out my integrated GPU (webGL stuff and Discord) and it doesn't switch unless I force it to use the dedicated gpu and restart them

Comment: How do you force it in those cases?

Comment: What happens when you change that setting from `auto-select` to `High-performance NVIDIA processor`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149534/discussion-between-reticivis-and-end-anti-semitic-hate).

Answer (score 1):

Per our chat, I recommended the following, and it sounded like it worked:

1. Open the NVIDIA Control Panel
2. Go to `Manage 3D Settings` > `Preferred Graphics Processor`
3. Select `High-performance NVIDIA processor`

[image: NVIDIA Control Panel]

Comment: I saw that in Dell's documentation too, but it doesn't work.  Windows still reports my Internal Display to be using the Intel(R) UHD Graphics.

Comment: @Tolga Is it possible that Windows is incorrectly reporting, as it is a separate Nvidia control panel in which the setting is applied?